# How can display pages with different states based on query parameters in next.js

Tags: next.js, next-router

I want to display pages with different states based on different query params in next.js , so that when a user uses a link with query param , It should not show the default page , but based on the state.

For simplicity
Coinsider the home page as  `localhost:3000`
This renders some default text 'Hello user'
If user enters `localhost:3000/?name=JohnDoe`
This should render Hello JohnDoe.

Things I have tried .
I am able to add the query param using event handler's via next router .
`router.push('/?name=JohnDoe)`
But I dont know of a solution to set the state when the user enters the page directly using the a link with query params

Comment: Can you show the full code of your attempt?

Comment: https://github.com/hussamkhatib/tap
check this file  components/students.tsx

Answer (score 0):

You can access the query in ***getServerSideProps*** and then redirect or do whatever you want with that query :

```
const getServerSideProps = (ctx) => {
   const {params} = ctx;
   
   if(params){
     return {
        redirect: {
        permanent: false,
        destination: "/login",
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: I am not using getServerSideProps as I want to redirect from the component and not the page.

Comment: @HussamKhatib with next js you can redirect to another page by using this method .

Answer (score 0):

To read query params, you should use `router.query`.

Here is an example that would render 'Hello user' on `localhost:3000`, and 'Hello JohnDoe' on `localhost:3000?name=JohnDoe`

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const Page = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const userName = router.query.name ?? 'user';

  return <div>Hello {userName}</div>;
};

export default Page;
```